# Basic batch file language command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to from my current command prompt open another command prompt and cd to a directory of my choice. I am currently doing the following:

```
start cmd /c "cd C:\Users"
```

I expect this to open a new command prompt and cd to that directory. I also expect it to show that cd command in the new command prompt. None of this is happening, only a brief second command window opening and closing out. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Start "New Window" Cmd /K "CD /D C:\Users"`. Type `Cmd /?`, `CD /?` and `Start /?` for help on their commands.

Comment: Also, as you have not provided much information about the purpose of the new cmd window, you may be able to utilise the `Start /D` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `pause`, do `cmd /k`.

- Flag *`c`* loses the cmd window.
- Flag *`k`* eeps the cmd window opens

So, your code should be:

```
start "windowTitle" cmd /k "cd C:\Users"
```

Comment: That will fail because start uses the first argument in double quotes as the window title.

Comment: Oh yeah. I didn't have a PC to test

Comment: Also @SteveFest, if you had seen my comment from hours earlier, you'd have seen the same answer given only more correct.

Comment: @compo yeah. I noticed it after I added the answer

Answer (score 1):

On the line below include "pause"
This will keep the window open promoting a key press. Keeping the cmd window open allows you to check it has done what you have asked. Cmd windows self terminate once all code has complete.

Comment: where to include the "pause" please? Could you edit your response with the modified command?

Comment: Try `start cmd /c "cd C:\Users && pause"`. If you want to see the current working directory in the new shell window, use `start cmd /c "cd C:\Users && cd && pause"`. (You can use `&&` to chain several commands together. The command on the right-hand side of the double ampersand will run only if the command on the left-hand side succeeded. `&&` is left-associative, i.e. the chained commands execute from left to right whenever you have several `&&`.)

Comment: Obviously, the OP wants the new command prompt to stay open to interact with it. There is no point in changing the current directory and then closing the command prompt.

Comment: @stakx The start command needs at least an empty pair of double quotes for the window title if there is any other quoted argument.

Comment: @LotPings: My examples above work fine on my Windows 8.0 machine without an additional pair of doublequotes. Could this be something OS version dependent?